# select2 multiple - not setting values

Tags: jquery-select2

I use **select2** v. 4.0.3 with angular2 and unable to pre-select values programmatically using **multiple** mode.

Based on previous answers, tried all these without luck:

```
    let m = this.preview.mutagList.map(function (i) { return i['id']; });
    console.log(m); // array of strings, which are the IDs for the options

    $(".mutag").val(m);

    $(".mutag").select2('val', m);

    $(".mutag").select2({}).select2('val', m);  

    $(".mutag").select2({}).select2('data', this.preview.mutagList);
```

This is the select:

```
<select name="mutag" id="mutag" multiple data-placeholder="xxx" class="select2 form-control" dir="rtl" >
        <option *ngFor="let c of mutagList" value="{{c.id}}">{{c.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Setting val() approach works for me in select2 with no multiple.

Please help!

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I am having the same issue